# How can Amazon Elastic Beanstalk take a custom python command?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I followed this tutorial to use Amazon Elastic Beanstalk to deploy a Flask (Python) web application: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-flask.html

However, my web application is built upon code written by other users. When I run the web application locally I run the command:

```
python web/chat_app.py --port 12345 --config web/app_params.json --schema-path data/bookhatball-schema.json --scenarios-path scenarios_generated.json --output out
```

I need to run this same python command when launching my web app to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

As per the AWS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html), you can customize your ElasticBeanstalk environment by using `.ebextensions`, and this includes running commands on instances during launch.

You can use the `commands` key to run any command on an ElasticBeanstalk instance. You can find more info on ElasticBeanstalk `commands` [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-commands).